# Closure Compiler & Performance with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, google-closure-compiler

Would running your scripts through the Closure Compiler make a difference in PhoneGap apps? Or does PhoneGap do something similar when you compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, running your scripts through the Google Closure Compiler would make a difference. The code would be smaller and thereby parsed quicker. As well as the other benefits that the Closure Compiler gives you with regards to code optimization.

No, PhoneGap does not do any concatenation or optimization of your JavaScript source code.